# Guessing ARMA order just from the plot

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection

[image]

I have this two plots, each one contains two realisations (orange/blue) of the same $ARMA(pi, qi)$ model.
All orange instances share the same noise sequence $e_i$, and so do all the blue ones.

I don't have the data, just the plots, so I can't use ACF or PACF

Now I need to identify to which configuration was used out of this 4:

$$ARMA(0,0)$$
$$ARMA(1,0)$$
$$ARMA(2,0)$$
$$ARMA(0,5)$$

How can I do this? How do the orders modify the graphs?